# User update function no longer works but should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, image-uploading

I installed Carrierwave and followed the instructions to get it working so that users could upload an image/avatar. My `avatar_uploader.rb` looks normal, I haven't really changed anything.

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "/images/"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :scale => [50, 50]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end

end
```

I added the image tag to the user edit part of the site (`_form.html.erb`), since it is a part of the users.

```
  <%= image_tag(@user.avatar_url) if @user.avatar? %>
  <p><%= f.file_field :avatar %></p>
  <%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %>
```

and to the `show.html.erb`:

```
<%= avatar_tag user.avatar_url(:thumb) if @user.avatar? %>
```

My `users_controller.rb` update function I haven't done much to change.

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and in this, the `user_params` seems okay.

```
   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :full_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar)
    end
```

When I try to update the user (i.e. upload a file) with the edit page, it gives me an error

```
undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass
```

and points to the `if @user.update` part of my users_controller file. It also seems to be taking in `"id"=>"username"` as a parameter. I have a vanity URL using my `routes.rb` file

`get "/:username",    to: "users#show",       as: "username"`

but when I click the update user button, it redirects back to `/users/username`. I'm not sure if this is causing it or if I didn't implement the avatar upload correctly. I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Edit: My `routes.rb` file looks as follows
      root  'home#index'

```
  get "users/new"
  get "/about" => "static_pages#about"
  get "/contact" => "static_pages#contact"
  get "/signedout" => "sessions#signout"

  post "login" => "sessions#login"

  resources :posts
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :login, :signout]

  match '/signin',    to: 'sessions#login',    via: 'get'
  match '/signup',    to: 'users#new',         via: 'get'
  match '/signedout', to: 'sessions#signout',  via: 'delete'

  get "/:username",    to: "users#show",       as: "username"
```

It's also showing the following Request parameters:

```
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"C2bHFQkNIjZ090wZhN4bLTJAl7Jqw4ZmRwyo3cmOQ5s=",
 "user"=>{"username"=>"jsamson",
 "email"=>"me@jsamson.com",
 "full_name"=>"Jesse Samson",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "avatar_cache"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Update User",
 "id"=>"jsamson"}
```

Comment: If you're using a catch-all wildcard route, you'll need to do some extensive exception handling in your `users#show` action. Just an observation – you may already be doing this...

Comment: I'm completely new to this, definitely a little in over my head. Would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: You've got a lot of stuff going on in this question – I'd rather tackle the question at hand. If you want to know more about exception handling, I'd suggest posting it in a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an instance of `User` in your `users#update` controller action:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) # Insert this as the first line of the method
  # remainder of code
end
```

As-is, your code is throwing an `undefined method 'update' for nil:NilClass` because `@user` is `nil`, and thus has no `update` method. Assigning the correct instance of `User` to the `@user` instance variable will resolve this issue.

**UPDATE**:

According to the request parameters cited in the question, the form is posting a *username* as the *id* parameter. In order to handle this, you'll want to retrieve the `User` by finding the record with the `username` matching the `params[:id]`:

```
def update
  User.find_by_username(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Okay, that was one of the answers I thought. If I overloaded that to be more along the lines of `@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])`, I would use that instead, right?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even though I threw that in.

Comment: Please update your question with the contents of your `routes.rb`.

Comment: Actually, because this is the `update` action (and not the `show` action), you will still likely access the correct `User` instance via `User.find(params[:id])`. Have you tried this so far?

Comment: It gives an error for that line when I put it in instead of the update line.

Comment: Instead of what "update line"? You shouldn't be substituting it for anything... you should be adding it as the first line in the method.

Comment: Haha, sorry. It gives an error for that line, the `User.find(params[:id])` when I put it in. Couldn't find User with `id=jsamson`

Comment: I've made an update to reflect this information. I think I've provided sufficient information to fix your problem, and I won't be making any follow-ups. If this answer has helped resolve your issue, please consider upvoting/accepting it as correct.